# Relationships with step-family

Tags: halacha, arayot

Recently, I chanced upon a screenshot of a Twitter post. In it, a woman who claimed that she once dated a man whose son her sister was dating at the same time. I found this to be a rather dubious scenario and was wondering if it fell into the list of *arayot*, in terms of either:

- Son's/Father's wife's sister
- Sister's husband's son/father

However, I am having trouble finding any corresponding scenarios mentioned either in Leviticus 18 or in the [Wikipedia summaries of the relevant texts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_views_on_incest#Karaite_views). Is this scenario in fact technically permissible (if perhaps still unscrupulous), or is there an interpretation that would see it as problematic?

Comment: Pretty sure that's A-Ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Shut Peulat Tzadik 1:4](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1716&st=&pgnum=26&hilite=) writes that this is permitted without any doubt.

This is also the opinion of Piskei HaRid (Yevamot 2a)

> וכן נמי יכול ראובן לישא אחות רחל שהיא
> אשת אביו